# [WPF ToolKit: How to set selected value from combobox to the current cell?

Tags: datagrid

I am using following code to bind combobox to the datagrid in wpf.

but when i select item from combobox and tab out, the grid does not hold the selected value.

I would like to set the selected value to the current cell of datagrid.

```
                                    <dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
                                        <col:ArrayList>
                                            <sys:String>A</sys:String>
                                            <sys:String>B</sys:String>
                                            <sys:String>C</sys:String>
                                            <sys:String>D</sys:String>
                                            <sys:String>E</sys:String>
                                        </col:ArrayList>
                                    </dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource>
                                </dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Please do the needful.

Comment: I really don't like datagrids.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedValueBinding="{Binding ProductID}"                                         
                                       SelectedValuePath="ProductID"
                                       DisplayMemberPath="ProductName"
                                       Header="Product"
                                       Width="135" 
                                       ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Product}}"
                                       SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Product}">
                    <dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```